# Hardware compatibility issues

Tags: debian, ubuntu, arch-linux, hardware-compatibility, kernel-parameters

I have recently switched to Linux and no matter what operating system I use or configurations I edit I can not seem to get Linux to work properly on my desktop pc where on my laptop Ubuntu worked straight out of the box.

From the research I've done I've concluded that it is a hardware problem and unsure which hardware specifically is causing the issue.

My specs are as follows:
CPU: Ryzen 3 2200g
GPU: Radeon 5500xt
RAM: G.Skill Ripjaws V 8GB 3200Mz
MoBo: MSI B350 Mortar
SSD: 250GB mushkin nvme drive

On some operating systems when I boot I get a error withe the nvme drive and I have to do a manual fix on it before I can boot but it doesn't solve all the problems.

Doesn't matter which operating system I boot it always gives a fatal kernel error which I solve by adding `iommu=soft` to the grub.

When I tried to use pop os I got an additional error where when ever I boot my keyboard completely stops working.

I hope there is someone that can help me with these problems and if not atleast tell me whether or not it is specific hardware I have causing the problems

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you boot Ubuntu, with `iommu=soft`, do you have any other issues?

Comment: Yes I also get issues when I try to run games from steam using proton, but most of those issues are resolved once I update the kernel from 5.4 to 5.5, and my wifi adapter often stops working randomly then I have to unplug it and plug it back in but I haven't noticed much other issues

Comment: So, I'm not really sure what it is that you still want to solve, the question is too broad. If it is a specific issue (for example Pop install, wireless adapter that stops working), please open a new question with just that one issue. It's the best way to call the attention of those who can help you fix it. Bundles of issues don't usually get many answers and they might not even be related.

Comment: Okay well my issue is actually just finding out whether or not it's a hardware issue or not (did I not specify that??)

Comment: Yes, you did mention that along with many other problems. Which one of them you want to know if it's hardware related? Would you consider for example the unavailability of an open source driver for your graphic card (if that were the case) a _hardware related problem_? That's why I suggest you tackle an issue at a time. But it's ok, maybe somebody with very similar hardware or experience will be able to help you.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice I will try to narrow it down a bit more